# can I hard wire the output power of a eu solar inverter to a us breaker panel/

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, signal-conversion

I have a hybrid solar Easun inverter/charger rated power 3000va/2400w 230vac 50/60hz self sensing. The unit is set up with single EU 230v self sensing 50/60hz input to charge battery and the output is also single EU 230v self sensing 50/60hz. I wish to use this system as a back up for when the grid goes down and to trick my Solaredge 7600 grid tied inverter into thinking it is tied to the grid so it will turn on when the grid is down and or panel main breaker it switched off and back up breaker is switched on. My question is... **Can I convert the EU output to US by connecting the blue and brown output wires of the Easun inverter to the 2 wire 230v breaker (L-1 and L-2) in my US panel box without hooking up the EU ground, trick my Soleredge inverter to turn on as it does when grid tied and maintain 110v to my normal house outlets?**  If I cannot connect the Easun inverter this way does anyone know how it can be done, with or without a converter between the output of the inverter and panel breakers input and vice versa.

Comment: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module) or, the power of data sheets and the irrelevance of wire colours as meaning anything without a schematic.

Comment: How is the Easun unit supposed to self sense whether to put out 50 or 60Hz when the grid is down?

Comment: The unit can also be set manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, because your neutral is floating, so any imbalance between L1 and L2 loads will cause imbalance between L1 and L2 voltage.

Perhaps it would work with a transformer tha has 230V input and center tapped 120V-0V-120V output, if you can get the grid tied inverter to turn on without a grid.

Comment: That sounds like what I need, do you know who makes and or sells them? I think this type of transformer will simulate the grid power and turn on my grid tied system. Thanks

Comment: No it does not emulate grid. A grid tie inverter will shut down along with mains grid, and will not start up until it sees mains grid AC voltage and has synchronized itself with it.

Comment: The concept was to get the eu inverter output to sync with the grid tied inverter and turn it on. If the center tapped transformer puts out 120v for L-1 and 120v for L-2 that would balance the 240 for L-1 and L-2 and the Hz is self sensing from the eu inverter to 60. I think I will experiment with a breaker box not connected to anything to see if I can get the output of the eu inverter to equalize 120v to L-1 and L-2 in the breaker box. Then I can test each side for the imbalance at least this way I won't damage anything.

Comment: I found the following page in a search let me know what you think. Thanks. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337166/is-it-okay-to-connect-a-european-240v-transformer-to-a-us-240v-outlet

Comment: How does that relate to anything? That question is about using a European 240V device in US between the two phases to get 240V without neutral.

Comment: Actually the question is can I convert the output power of the eu inverter to us power and trick my grid tied system to turn on as if connected to the grid when the grid is either down or switched off at the main breaker.